# %matplotlib inline does not show any plot on jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

`matplotlib.pyplot` takes a long time to run and finally no plot shows on the screen

But `matplotlib.back_end()` gives the following

```
u'TkAgg'
```

Can someone suggest a solution?

NOTE: I installed matplotlib using `pip install matplotlib`

Comment: I thought `matplotlib.pyplot` would generate a graph, but then you'd have to invoke `matplotlib.pyplot.show` if you wanted it to show (interactively)

Comment: I used `matplotlib.pyplot.plot ( test_data["coln1"], test_data["coln2"], ".")` but still got no output @doctorlove

Comment: ... meaning the import takes ages?

Comment: No, it takes quite a bit of time and then finally stops but without any output

Comment: Are you calling `show`?

Comment: No, I am just using `plot`

Comment: Try running  `%matplotlib notebook` or `%matplotlib inline` as the very first cell.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem working with jupyter notebook on a Mac OSX 10.10.5

In the end I fixed it by reinstalling IPython and dependencies with the command

```
pip install -U --force-reinstall numpy matplotlib pyzmq jinja2 ipython
```