# Matplotlib shows nothing in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am working with Matplotlib and came across with Object Oriented Method to create plots with Matplotlib. So I wrote the following code in Jupyter Notebook

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline   

x=np.linspace(0,5,11)
y=x**2
fig=plt.figure()
axes=fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
axes.plot(x,y)
```

But I don't get any plot after running it. I tried looking other answers but couldn't solve my problem. So, my question is how do Object Oriented Interface in Matplotlib actually works and how and why it is better than functional method of Matplotlib?
Thanks.

Comment: you still have to run `plt.show()`. The reason for the object orientated, is that you can now handle multiple figures separately. Also take a look at `fig, axes = plt.subplots()` .

Comment: adding plt.show() doesn't give the plot also.

Comment: This probably is an installation issue, see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105238/matplotlib-inline-does-not-show-any-plot-on-jupyter-notebook) where somebody suggests reinstalling IPython and matplotlib.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue. I just placed commands _axes=fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])_ and _axes.plot(x,y)_ in a single cell in Jupyter Notebook and was able to get the plots. Not able to figure out why they don't work when placed and run from different cells.

Comment: @Thymen "you still have to run `plt.show()`" <- huh that's strange, I'm able to plot in jupyter without `show()`